# How to remove the IPv6 part of the docker ports output?

Tags: docker

I'm formatting the `ps` docker command as such:

```
 sudo docker ps --format "table {{.ID}}:\t\t{{.Status}}\t\t{{.Ports}}\t\t{{.Names}}"
```

I dont need the IPv6 output in the ports column. How can I strip it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with this data, but would it be easier to use the [Docker API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/) in a higher-level language?

Answer (score 0):

Its not optimal but this is already bit better:

```
docker ps --format \"table {{.ID}}\t{{.Status}}\t{{.Ports}}\t{{.Names}}\" | sed -E 's/,\s:::[0-9]+\S*//g'
```

Only annoying thing is, the `NAMES` columns header is offset to the right.. interesting.